# Can't access spring boot admin behind zuul gateway

Tags: spring-boot, cors, netflix-zuul, spring-boot-admin

My spring boot admin is not accessible through zuul gateway, he shows me Cors origin problem ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxVZ9.png))

But it works fine from his own host !

Spring boot admin version 2.4.1

Spring boot version 2.4.

Github project for more info : https://github.com/SeifBh/spring-project

Help please !

Comment: By pass the option request in your zuul gateway.

Comment: Already did but always not working , https://github.com/SeifBh/spring-project/blob/main/service-proxy/src/main/resources/application.properties#L4

Comment: Not able to see spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request this property in your code

Answer (score 0):

For accessing spring boot admin via zuul, you need to specify property `spring.boot.admin.ui.public-url` , the value of the property will be your zuul host.
Checkout [this](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_running_behind_a_front_end_proxy_server) for more details.